# Icefaces 3.0.1 FileEntry: FileEntryListener is never called

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, icefaces, icefaces-3

1.1, IceFaces 3.0.1 and JSF 2.1 and was trying to work with ace:fileentry. I can't understand why the listener is never called! Even the IDE sends me a warning "pruebaBean.sampleListener is an unknown property".
Here is a short example of what i'm doing. When click the submit button nothing happen.
Can someone help me ?? Could be some kind of bug?

prueba.xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
       xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
       xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
       xmlns:ace="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components">
 
 <h:head>
 </h:head>
 <h:body>
     <ice:form id="usuarioForm">
         <ice:panelGrid columns="2">
             <ace:fileEntry id="fileEntryImage" absolutePath="c:\iTablero\imagenes"
                             useSessionSubdir="false" useOriginalFilename="false"
                             fileEntryListener="#{pruebaBean.sampleListener}"/>
             <ice:commandButton type="submit" value="Subir archivo"/>
         </ice:panelGrid>
         <ice:messages/>
     </ice:form>
 </h:body>
```

PruebaBean.java:

```
 package com.itablero.backingbeans;

 import java.io.Serializable;
 import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
 import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
 import org.icefaces.ace.component.fileentry.FileEntry;
 import org.icefaces.ace.component.fileentry.FileEntryEvent;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

 @ManagedBean
 @Controller
 @RequestScoped
 public class PruebaBean implements Serializable {
 
     public void sampleListener (FileEntryEvent e) {
         System.out.println("it work!");
         FileEntry fe = (FileEntry) e.getComponent();
         //some others operations
     }
 }
```

---

## Update 1

Thanks to @fischermatte I found the problem was replace ice:commandButton for h:commandButton. But when I applied this to the original complete form and didn't work. The fileEntryListener method is never called. Can someone see the error here?
Logically the previous example and the code below have the same web.xml, faces-config.xml, etc. Note the button to submit the file is h:commandButton, and there is a ice:commandButton for complete form. I already tried to change this por en h:cb.
Here is the original form (that is display in a popup/modal window) and bean:

usuariosList.xhtml

```
                <ice:panelPopup rendered="#{usuariosBean.showPopup}"
                            visible="#{usuariosBean.showPopup}"
                            modal="true"
                            autoCentre="true">

                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:panelGroup>
                        <h:panelGroup style="float: left;">
                            Usuario
                        </h:panelGroup>
                        <h:panelGroup style="float: right;">
                            <ice:form>
                            <h:commandButton image="/resources/images/popup-close.png"
                                            alt="Cerrar" title="Cerrar"
                                            style="height: 11px; width: 11px; border: 0;"
                                            action="#{usuariosBean.closePopup}"/>
                            </ice:form>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="body">
                    <ice:form id="usuarioForm">
                        <ice:panelGrid columns="2">
                            <p>Nombre:</p>
                            <ice:inputText id="nombre" label="nombre" value="#{usuariosBean.usuario.nombre}" size="40" />
                            <p>Imagen:</p>
                            <ice:graphicImage value="#{usuariosBean.usuario.imagen}"/>
                            <ace:fileEntry id="fileEntryImage" absolutePath="c:\iTablero\imagenes"
                                            useSessionSubdir="false" useOriginalFilename="false"
                                            fileEntryListener="#{usuariosBean.formListener}"/>
                            <h:commandButton type="submit" value="Subir archivo"/>
                        </ice:panelGrid>
                        <ice:messages for="usuarioForm"/>
                        <ice:commandButton value="Guardar" action="#{usuariosBean.save()}" />
                    </ice:form>
                </f:facet>                    
            </ice:panelPopup>
```

UsuariosBean.java

```
package com.itablero.backingbeans;

import com.itablero.excepciones.DAOException;
import com.itablero.modelo.Usuario;
import com.itablero.servicios.AdminService;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import org.icefaces.ace.component.fileentry.FileEntry;
import org.icefaces.ace.component.fileentry.FileEntryEvent;
import org.icefaces.ace.component.fileentry.FileEntryResults;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@ManagedBean
@Controller
@ViewScoped
public class UsuariosBean implements Serializable {

@Autowired
private AdminBean adminBean;
@Autowired
private AdminService adminService;
private Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
private boolean showPopup;

//getter and setters 

public boolean isShowPopup() {
    return showPopup;
}

public void setShowPopup(boolean showPopup) {
    this.showPopup = showPopup;
}


public void openPopup() {
    this.showPopup = true;
}

public void closePopup() {
    this.showPopup = false;
    this.usuario = new Usuario();
}

public String edit(Usuario usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
    this.showPopup = true;
    return "usuariosList";
}

public String delete(Usuario usuario) {
    adminService.delete(usuario);
    return "usuariosList";
}

public String save() {
    try {
        usuario.setTutor(adminBean.getLoggedTutor());
        adminService.save(usuario);
    } catch (DAOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TutoresBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    usuario = new Usuario();
    this.showPopup = false;
    return "usuariosList";
}

public void formListener(FileEntryEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Entro");
    FileEntry fe = (FileEntry)e.getComponent();
    FileEntryResults results = fe.getResults();
    //other stuff
}

}
```

---

## Update 2

I think I figured out why is not working, but need some help with the fix. I made the corrections as @fischermatte advice me, but didn't work.

To reach this page with the form, first have to navigate throw a the main page `/admin/admin.html`, if a look the URL in the browser appears `http://localhost:8084/iTablero/admin/admin.html`. This page has a menu, one of this menu options bring me to the page with the problematic form. But, because is an AJAX call (if i'm not wrong) the URL in the browser does not change, it keeps the `http://localhost:8084/iTablero/admin/admin.html`. And the fileEntry never calls the listener.
Now, if I enter the URL by myself `http://localhost:8084/iTablero/admin/usuariosList.html`, the page is displayed correctly as before, but now THE FILEENTRY WORKS PERFECTLY!!!
I have no idea how to fix this, will have to use redirects? I think is something around AJAX.......help pls! :-D

---

## Update 3

That is the menu, without redirect is not working.

```
       <h:form>
            <ice:menuBar orientation="horizontal">
                <ice:menuItem value="Tutores" action="tutoresList"/>
                <ice:menuItem value="Usuarios" action="usuariosList"/>
                <ice:menuItem value="Tableros" action="tablerosList"/>
                <ice:menuItem value="Simbolos" action="simbolosList"/>
                <ice:menuItem value="Estadisticas" action="estadisticas"/>
                <ice:menuItem value="Salir" action="#{adminBean.logout()}"/>
            </ice:menuBar>
       </h:form>
```

With `action="usuariosList?faces-redirect=true"` works fine.
Already test with forward navigation to a basic page form with only a FileEntry and doesn't work too. Again, if I use redirect, works fine. I think is some kind of issue with this component and forward navigation.

Comment: can you paste your faces-config.xml file and your web.xml and also complete java bean and complete xhtml, i am working on fileEntry module right now and could help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JSF's commandbutton instead of icefaces's: `<h:commandButton type="submit" value="Subir archivo"/>`. It is a known issue in ICEFaces, see [ace:fileEntry wiki](http://wiki.icesoft.org/display/ICE/FileEntry).

**Update 1**

Plus you either remove the rendered attribute in the popup or update the popup when opening it like here:

```xhtml
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="Show Popup" action="#{usuariosBean.showPopupAction}">
        <f:ajax render=":popupPanelGroup"/>
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
<h:panelGroup id="popupPanelGroup">
    <ice:panelPopup visible="#{usuariosBean.showPopup}" rendered="#{usuariosBean.showPopup}" modal="true" autoCentre="true">
     ...
    </ice:panelPopup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: You're right, thats was the problem in the example posted! I use h:commandButton and the actionListener is called. But the strange thing is when I apply this to the complete form and didn't work. I'll post the complete form editing the original question.

Comment: This has something to do with how you open the popup i guess. Will it work when you remove the rendered attribute and just write `<ice:panelPopup visible="#{usuariosBean.showPopup}" modal="true" autoCentre="true">`?

Comment: Mmmm...I think I found the problem, but don't know how to fix i. Will be hard to explain in my awful english.

Comment: Can you provide the code of admin.html containing the menu for navigation? I assume you are using a `<h:commandButton/>` with an action. In JSF this will make a forward using POST. When you want the page URL to be changed in browser, you either take a simple html link like `<a href="http://.../usuariosList.html">MyLink</a>` or have a jsf 2.0 link like `<h:link outcome="usuariosList.html" value="MyLink"/>`. In case you need to submit form data, you can also stick to the CommandButton and use the POST-REDIRECT-GET approach:  `<h:commandButton action="usuariosList.html?faces-redirect=true`/>.

Comment: I have ice:menuBar with ice:menuItem. I think this works like h:commandButton. Added, as you advice, `<ice:menuItem value="Usuarios" action="usuariosList?faces-redirect=true"/>` and work good changing the URL and FileEntry also works fine. But this solution makes a browser refresh, is no exactly what I wanted. There is no another workaround for FileEntry to work without redirect? Is imperative for FE that the URL is exactly pointing to the page where this component is defined?

Comment: In JSF 1.x times, a lot of applications where using this "forward" approach, meaning that navigation actions did not lead to a url change. I consider this as quite ugly, since you can not manually refresh the browser or open links in a new tab.

Comment: However FileEntry should also work with ice:menuItem, but I would need to see your html code containing the menu. There must be an update issue as mentioned before.

Comment: Hm sorry, can't help there. I played a little around, it seems to be a bug in ICEFaces :( However, if you have any chance switching to another component library do this (e.g. Primefaces). I was working quite some time now with icefaces 2 and 3 and had to struggle with a lot of weird issues. JSF development became a lot easier and was suddenly fun after switching to Primefaces.

Comment: No problem, you were rigth about that forward is a little annoying, and redirect is better. So, I just going to use redirect and anything will work fine. Anyway you have been a great help!! Thanks, and sorry for my weird english, jeje!